# Can cards that say "deal damage to any target" deal damage to a planeswalker?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-planeswalkers

I have a card that says "whenever [Karplusan Hound](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarplusan%20Hound%5d) attacks, attacks, if you control a Chandra planeswalker, this creature deals 2 damage to any target."

Does this mean I can target a planeswalker?

Comment: I'd love to see this "attract" mechanic :D

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, *any target* includes planewalkers**

The wording was a relatively recent change. Previously, very few damage-dealing spells and abilities could target planeswalkers directly. Instead, you redirected damage from targeted players to one of their planeswalkers at resolution.

> 114.4. Some spells and abilities that refer to damage require “any target,” “another target,” “two targets,” or similar rather than “target [something].” These targets may be creatures, players, or planeswalkers. Other game objects, such as noncreature artifacts or spells, can’t be chosen.